# Reverse proxy with sub-directories using nginx and nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I am having trouble setting up reverse proxy with nginx forwarding requests to node sitting a the back end.
My nginx conf file is :

```
 server{
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.50.176;



location /stretch {
    rewrite /stretch/(.*) /$1 break
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Without subdirectories it works just fine.The below config works :

```
server{
    listen 80;        
    server_name 192.168.50.176;



location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```